# Adding ViewPager inside another ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

[image]

I'm creating an activity showing some photos with ViewPager. And I want to add another little ViewPager into any page of main ViewPager. When I swipe little ViewPager main ViewPager swipes. I want main ViewPager not to swipe.

How can I do it?

Note: I add all the elements by programmatically.

```
                RelativeLayout RelLay=(RelativeLayout) viewPager.findViewById(arg0); //main ViewPager page
                final ViewPager vpager=new ViewPager(getBaseContext());
                ArrayList<String> childImages=new ArrayList<String>();
                childImages.add("/storage/sdcard0/Folder/1.jpg");
                childImages.add("/storage/sdcard0/Folder/2.jpg");
                childImages.add("/storage/sdcard0/Folder/3.jpg");
                childImages.add("/storage/sdcard0/Folder/4.jpg");
                childImages.add("/storage/sdcard0/Folder/5.jpg");
                ImageAdapterChild imageadapter=new ImageAdapterChild(getBaseContext(), childImages);
                vpager.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                vpager.setAdapter(imageadapter);
                RelLay.addView(vpager); //add child ViewPager into the main ViewPager
```